# Android application error after export APK

Tags: android, eclipse

If I got the apk from "bin" file, the app is work well. But if I export the apk, then the app will got errors, no matter I use Proguard or not. Why???

Also, I find a very interesting thing. I tried to export the apk many times (like more than 100 times), sometime I can export a good apk. And the good apk size(1.92 MB) will smaller than the error apk(1.20 MB).

Error

```
    08-31 02:25:11.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3947): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    08-31 02:25:11.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3947): java.lang.NullPointerException
    08-31 02:25:11.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3947):     at com.queue.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(Unknown Source)
    08-31 02:25:11.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3947):     at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2577)
    08-31 02:25:11.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3947):     at android.support.v4.app.j.onCreatePanelMenu(Unknown Source)
    08-31 02:25:11.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3947):     at android.support.v7.a.g.a(Unknown Source)
    08-31 02:25:11.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3947):     at android.support.v7.a.l.a(Unknown Source)
    08-31 02:25:11.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3947):     at android.support.v7.a.g.onCreatePanelMenu(Unknown Source)
    08-31 02:25:11.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3947):     at android.support.v7.a.m.onCreatePanelMenu(Unknown Source)
    08-31 02:25:11.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3947):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:414)
    08-31 02:25:11.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3947):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:777)
    08-31 02:25:11.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3947):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:199)
    08-31 02:25:11.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3947):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
    08-31 02:25:11.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3947):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    08-31 02:25:11.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3947):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
    08-31 02:25:11.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3947):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5390)
    08-31 02:25:11.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3947):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    08-31 02:25:11.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3947):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    08-31 02:25:11.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3947):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    08-31 02:25:11.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3947):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    08-31 02:25:11.759: E/AndroidRuntime(3947):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    08-31 02:25:11.759: W/ActivityManager(448):   Force finishing activity com.queue/.MainActivity
    08-31 02:25:11.769: E/IMGSRV(165): :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 71
```

Code

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    SearchManager SManager =  (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchViewAction = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMenuItem);
    searchViewAction.setSearchableInfo(SManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Are you getting your apk from the /out folder?

Comment: Yes, I set the destination of the export file in desktop.